# Google Search Console API permissions on sudomains

Tags: php, permissions, subdomain, google-search-console, google-search-api

Good day!

I have a series of domains on Google Search Console:

- *domain.eu*
- *sub.domain.eu*
- *test.sub.domain.eu*

I have permissions for all three of them as Domain property (without protocol prefixes).
I want to use the GSC API (PHP) to scrape the data but for some reasons, I get an "insufficient credentials" error message when I try to run my request against *sub.domain.eu* and *test.sub.domain.eu*

```
    Google_Service_Webmasters->searchanalytics->query($siteUrl, $query);
```

In the error message I see that it tries to access http://sub.domain.eu but I can't find a way to force the GSC API to use the https version.

Did anybody have a similar problem and get give me a hint how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was enough to add the protocol to the site:

```
    $siteUrl = "https://sub.domain.eu"
```

even though

```
    $siteUrl = "domain.eu"
```

was working just fine